# Fortran program produces empty output

Tags: fortran

For a college course I'm required  to work with Fortran77 codes which I know nothing about. Programs are prewritten, we only change input. On my computer though programs produce no output (they create a file, but it's empty). The very same code works on other computers. I treid using FLUSH and it didn't work. I use Force 2.0 as my programming enviroment. Something I can do about this?

Comment: Without seeing you code there is no way to tell what is wrong!  You could add "write(*,*) variable_name" to see if code will print to screen. If the file is not too long you could include it in your question.

Comment: Please see [ask]. We can't really help you, there is not nearly enough information in your uestion to even guess.